# How to change the maximum size of the file uploaded Java Post

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, size

I take back the program of a colleague.

He did the method (This program allows to upload a file on a server):

```
protected String uploadFile(File inputFile, String uuidFile) throws IOException,
        ClientProtocolException {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(new StringBuilder()
            .append("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/FileServlet/").append("/uploadFile")
            .toString());
    post.addHeader("UuidFile", uuidFile);

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(inputFile));
    HttpEntity httpEntity = builder.build();

    post.setEntity(httpEntity);

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(post);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("File uploaded into (.*)</h2>");
            String messageErreur = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            System.out.println(messageErreur);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(messageErreur);
            if (m.find()) {
                return m.group(1);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ": " + new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent())));
        }
        return null;
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

The error in the console is

> There was an error: the request was rejected because its size
>   (68142301) exceeds the configured maximum (52428800)

However I don't know how to augment the maximum size of the file uploaded...

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,
Arnaud

Comment: Does the server belong to you?

Comment: The server is a DEV server. I have not the program of uploadFile side server. However, I see in Tomcat/webapp the war of the server and the repertory associated (containing WEB-INF, META-INF) . I have changed the web.xml in the repertory WEB-INF adding your suggestion and it doesn't function... It had not "multipart-config" in the web.xml in the repertory on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the error as of now Check your web.xml for the below configuration in the servlet. Increase the size and check.

```
 <multipart-config>   
    <max-file-size>68142301</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>68142301</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

It functions, an other colleague gave project side serve, it had

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // sets maximum size of upload file
        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);

        // sets maximum size of request (include file + form data)
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
```

to change